# Can an rpm package install dependencies in sequence?

Tags: rpm, packaging

I have a custom rpm package being installed in CentOS which has a dependency which is not included in the default repo. This needs to be able to spin up on demand in Jenkins and the way the process is set-up I can't install the dependency ahead of time.

Is there a way for one dependency to be installed, AND THEN have another (which relies on the first) be installed afterwards? When I run the build it won't install the package I need, because it can't find it, I need to add the epel repo first.

Comment: Are you asking if your package can force the installation of the EPEL repo on a system during its install?

Comment: My package depends on a package that is only in epel, and I don't want to get into building anything from source if I can avoid it, as the package has terrible documentation and I have wasted enough time trying to do that. If I add `Requires: epel-release, package-i-need` the install fails. I want to know if there is a way to resolve a dependency only after another is resolved.

Comment: The problem is that RPM dependency resolution can only work on packages that it is able to see available.  If EPEL isn't enabled, there's no way for yum or rpm to "know" that it is in a repo it has no metadata on.